# A committee of 4 picking from a pool of 5 men and 4 women. What is the probability that there are more women than men on the committee?

Tags: probability

I am approaching this problem with two ways:

1) Brute force method: physically laying out all possible outcomes and count the outcomes in which there are women than men.

2) Using counting principles:  Applying counting principles, combining with laws of probability.

So, my first method goes like this:

1. I listed out all the possible outcomes ($2^{4}$ outcomes), and I have the following:

{(M, M, M, M), (W, M, M, M), (M, W, M, M), (M, M, W, M), 
(M, M, M, W), (W, W, M, M), (M, W, W, M), (M, M, W, W), 
(W, M, M, W), (W, W, W, M), (W, W, M, W), (W, W, W, M), 
(W, M, W, W), (W, W, M, W), (W, W, W, M), (W, W, W, W)}

So, the probability is obviously 7/16.

2. Now, I am trying to get the same result using counting principles and probability theorems (and here is I have almost always have difficulty with).

let A be the number of woman in the pool, and B be the number of men in the pool.

So, the probability of picking will be P(A)+ P(B).

Then, I figure that the probability (without the condition of women more than men) will be

$$\frac{1}{5!}+\frac{1}{4!}=\frac{3}{20}$$

Then, I get stuck because it appears that my thinking is not correct. And even if I am half way there, how do I account for the probability of the 16 outcomes for picking the committee members and then focusing on the outcomes that there are more women than men?

Comment: In your first method, the result is not correct because the outcomes are not equally likely.

Comment: I know there is something wrong. Thank you for pointing out. But what is the correct way?

Comment: You need either four women or three women and one man. Use the *choose* function (binomial distribution) to find the number of qualifying groups, then divide by the number of unrestricted groups. See my comment on Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to select 4 people out of 9. To get more men than women you need to either get $(4,0), (3,1), (2,2)$. The probability of the compliment is

$$
1-\bigg(\frac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{9}{4}} +\frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{9}{4}} + \frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{4}} \bigg)
$$

Comment: Direct count: $\frac{\binom{4}{4}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{9}{4}}$